# SQL Server Select one column by aggregate but not another

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select

Not good with sql. Forgive me if the question isn't 100% clear. Here is my query

```
SELECT 
     MAX(PatientId),
  [Date],
  [Time],
  CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(HealthScoreSkipped as INT)) = 1
    THEN '--'
    ELSE MAX(DailyHealthScore)
  END DailyHealthScore,
  ProtocolGroupName,
  MAX(BloodPressure) BloodPressure,
  MAX(SystolicAlert) SystolicAlert,
  MAX(DiastolicAlert) DiastolicAlert,
  MAX(BloodPressureSkipped) BloodPressureSkipped,
  MAX(Pulse) Pulse,
  MAX(PulseAlert) PulseAlert,
  MAX(PulseSkipped) PulseSkipped,
  MAX(BloodSugar) BloodSugar,
  MAX(BloodSugarAlert) BloodSugarAlert,
  MAX(BloodSugarSkipped) BloodSugarSkipped,
  MAX(Steps) Steps,
  MAX(StepsAlert) StepsAlert,
  MAX(StepsSkipped) StepsSkipped,
  MAX(O2) O2,
  MAX(O2Alert) O2Alert,
  MAX(O2Skipped) O2Skipped,
  MAX(Weight) Weight,
  MAX(WeightAlert) WeightAlert,
  @BaselineWeight AS BaselineWeight,
  MAX(WeightSkipped) WeightSkipped,
  MAX(Temperature) Temperature,
  MAX(TemperatureAlert) TemperatureAlert,
  MAX(TemperatureUnit) TemperatureUnit,
  MAX(TemperatureSkipped) TemperatureSkipped,
  MAX(PEF) PEF,
  MAX(PEFAlert) PEFAlert,
  MAX(PEFSkipped) PEFSkipped,
  MAX(FEV1) FEV1,
  MAX(FEV1Alert) FEV1Alert,
  MAX(FEV1Skipped) FEV1Skipped,
  MAX(FEVRatio) FEVRatio,
  MAX(FEVRatioAlert) FEVRatioAlert,
  MAX(FEVRatioSkipped) FEVRatioSkipped,
  @SpiroEnabled SpiroEnabled
   FROM @bioAndScores
    GROUP BY PatientId, Date, Time, ProtocolGroupName
```

The problem here is on the lines

```
MAX(Steps) Steps,
MAX(StepsAlert) StepsAlert
```

I want to select the max Steps but the stepalert value that goes with that row not the max of the stepAlert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a sub query in the select statement to get the steps alert that corresponds to your step.
something along the lines of the below (note that I'm not sure why you are grouping by patientId, if you are taking the max(patientId) if you do want to group by patient id, the where clause of the sub query should also match on patient Id

```
SELECT 
    MAX(bas.PatientId),
    bas.[Date],
    bas.[Time],
    bas.ProtocolGroupName,
    .
    .
    .
    MAX(bas.Steps) Steps,
    --sub query to get the StepsAlert that corresponds to max steps
    (SELECT 
        StepsAlert 
    FROM 
        @bioAndScores subBas 
    WHERE
        --This is the important part of finding the match for Max Steps
        MAX(bas.Steps) = subBas.Steps AND
        --commented out because the MAX(PatientId) was ambiguous
        --bas.PatientId = subBas.PatientId AND
        bas.[Date] = subBas.[Date] AND
        bas.[Time] = subBas.[Time] AND
        bas.ProtocolGroupName = subBas.ProtocolGroupName) as StepsAlert 
FROM
    @bioAndScores as bas
GROUP BY
    --PatientId, 
    bas.Date, 
    bas.Time, 
    bas.ProtocolGroupName
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the MAX() function from StepAlerts and add StepAlerts to your GROUP BY clause.

```
MAX(Steps) AS Steps,
StepsAlert AS StepsAlert
```

And in your GROUP BY:

```
GROUP BY PatientId, Date, Time, ProtocolGroupName, StepAlerts
```

Comment: This is close but what that does is give me two or more rows. I want the stepAlert That corresponds to the rows with the highest steps.

Comment: What's the overall goal of the query?

Comment: Well lots of stuff. But there are rows where StepAlert Corresponse to Steps.  I want to return a row with the highest number of steps and the StepAlert that corresponse to that row. So a steps of 9000 will always return 3 a steps of 5 will always return 1. I want to return a row with 9000 and 3 if there are two rows one with 9000 for steps and 3 for alert and one with 5 for steps and 1 for step alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `StepsAlert` column to the group by clause and remove the `MAX` aggregate function.

```
GROUP BY PatientId, Date, Time, ProtocolGroupName,StepsAlert
```

I would suggest you go through  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) to better understand about how group by works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [**`apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) to select the set of values that correspond to the highest `Steps` at the earliest `StepsAlert` like so:

```
select 
    PatientId
  , [Date]
  , [Time]
  , DailyHealthScore    = case 
      when MAX(CAST(HealthScoreSkipped as int))= 1 then '--' 
      else MAX(DailyHealthScore) 
      end 
  , ProtocolGroupName
  , BloodPressure       = MAX(BloodPressure)
  , SystolicAlert       = MAX(SystolicAlert)
  , DiastolicAlert      = MAX(DiastolicAlert)
  , BloodPressureSkipped= MAX(BloodPressureSkipped)
  , Pulse               = MAX(Pulse)
  , PulseAlert          = MAX(PulseAlert)
  , PulseSkipped        = MAX(PulseSkipped)
  , BloodSugar          = MAX(BloodSugar)
  , BloodSugarAlert     = MAX(BloodSugarAlert)
  , BloodSugarSkipped   = MAX(BloodSugarSkipped)
  , Steps               = x.Steps
  , StepsAlert          = x.StepsAlert
  , StepsSkipped        = MAX(StepsSkipped)
  , O2                  = MAX(O2)
  , O2Alert             = MAX(O2Alert)
  , O2Skipped           = MAX(O2Skipped)
  , Weight              = MAX(Weight)
  , WeightAlert         = MAX(WeightAlert)
  , BaselineWeight      = @BaselineWeight
  , WeightSkipped       = MAX(WeightSkipped)
  , Temperature         = MAX(Temperature)
  , TemperatureAlert    = MAX(TemperatureAlert)
  , TemperatureUnit     = MAX(TemperatureUnit)
  , TemperatureSkipped  = MAX(TemperatureSkipped)
  , PEF                 = MAX(PEF)
  , PEFAlert            = MAX(PEFAlert)
  , PEFSkipped          = MAX(PEFSkipped)
  , FEV1                = MAX(FEV1)
  , FEV1Alert           = MAX(FEV1Alert)
  , FEV1Skipped         = MAX(FEV1Skipped)
  , FEVRatio            = MAX(FEVRatio)
  , FEVRatioAlert       = MAX(FEVRatioAlert)
  , FEVRatioSkipped     = MAX(FEVRatioSkipped)
  , SpiroEnabled        = @SpiroEnabled
from @bioAndScores b
  cross apply (
    select top 1
        i.Steps
      , i.StepsAlert
    from @bioAndScores i
    where b.PatientId = i.PatientId
      and b.[Date] = i.[Date]
      and b.[Time] = i.[Time]
      and b.ProtocolGroupName = i.ProtocolGroupName
    order by i.Steps desc, i.StepsAlert asc
      ) x
group by 
    PatientId
  , date
  , time
  , ProtocolGroupName
```